# How do I mount an already existing php app to an empty azure php web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Ok so I created an empty php web app in Azure, and I already have an existing php app that I have only tested locally, question is: How do I "transfer" that app to that empty php web app I created in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

To migrate your existing PHP app to Azure Web Apps, you might need to do the following things:

1. Deploy all files of your PHP app to a virtual directory's root (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) using FTP or source control:

   - [Deploy your app to Azure App Service using FTP/S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp)
   - [Local Git Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git)
2. [Configure PHP in Azure App Service Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure)

Azure Web Apps run on Microsoft IIS. If you have ever had your project run on Apache Web server, you also need to [translate `.htaccess` ontent to IIS `web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).